# Windbg Break on Memory Range

Tags: windows, debugging

How can I set a break on access for a specific memory range? ba only accepts a single address. I would prefer not to write a script unless there isn't any other way.

Comment: this might be relevant (also explains why `ba` is limited to pointer size): http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2011/03/23/memory-access-breakpoint-for-large-ranges-using-virtualprotect/

Answer (score 0):

You have to develop a plugin to do that in Windbg. [This page](http://reversingonwindows.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/data-access-breakpoint-using-memory.html) describes the logic to develop such plugin.

Alternatively you can try Ollydbg because the latest version has the ability to place breakpoint for a memory range.